# Convert first 2 letters of all records to Uppercase in python

Tags: python, dataframe, uppercase, capitalize, toupper

I have a dataframe DF with just 1 column and I want to uppercase first 2 letters of all the records in python. how do I do that ?

Comment: What dataframe? What have you tried?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Hj Sin
df['Name']

Comment: I want to capitalize first 2 letters of all records in the 'Name' Column of my Dataframe df

Comment: Please post sample of your dataframe (something like `print(df.head())`), desired output and snippet of your source code that you tried

Comment: save all of your record into list and then use like below: `[x[0:2].upper() + x[2::] for x in your_list]`

Comment: @Chris
if a name is ysingh then I want to make it YSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use map and Convert you data as you required:

try below:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['geeks', 'gor', 'geeks', 'is','portal', 'for','geeks']})
df['name']=df['name'].map(lambda x: x[:2].upper()+x[2:])
print (df)
```

output:

```
     name
0   GEeks
1     GOr
2   GEeks
3      IS
4  POrtal
5     FOr
6   GEeks
```

[demo](https://repl.it/repls/UnsungCarefulInfo)

Comment: Thank you @FrustratedDeveloper for the help

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement what Yeganeh suggested in the comments,

```
list = []
for items in df['Name']:
    list.append(items)
newlist = ([x[0:2].upper() + x[2::] for x in list])
print(df.replace(list,newlist))
```

Replace the previous list with the new one.